# What should our chatroom name be?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, chatroom

Stealing from a number of sites, I've decided to bring up the question of what the chatroom's name should be. Sites all over SE have creative, cool room names that not only are related to the site but bring some diversity from our chatroom and others. And our chatroom is lame/bland. I mean look at the other sites:

- "Root Access" for Super User
- "The DMZ" for Security
- "The Renderfarm" for Blender
- "The Litter Box" for Pets
- "The Hangar" for Aviation
- "You Are Here" for Travel

So, what should our chatroom be renamed to? Please only one entry per answer and the name with the highest score wins!

Comment: You should accept Numeri's answer, as that's what our chatroom is now called.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### The Language Lab

This is a throwback to school, i.e., the room dedicated to language learning. It is generally filled with computers ready to run language-learning software, or language-themed posters.

Comment: You had this at your school? Never heard of it before.

Comment: @fi12 Language labs went out of fashion in the 1980s. Although there are language schools that still use them, but probably not in the same way as originally intended. (Hmm, there may be an LL SE question in here.)

Answer (score 8):

## Language Café

Many language exchange groups around here call themselves "language café". Although I had never heard the term before I moved here, so it may not be a well known name.

Answer (score 7):

## The Polyglots' Place

Merriam Webster defines polyglotism as: *the use of many languages, the ability to speak many languages*. That fits what we are about.

Comment: I think adding a The to the beginning would make this sound better

Answer (score 3):

## [Lorem Ipsum](http://www.lipsum.com/)

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse in rhoncus nibh.

> Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

Comment: Translation please!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Latin. Ref: http://www.lipsum.com/

Comment: Why the spoiler markup?

Comment: To have the first wth reaction. First was without it, but people got confused and expecting some translation.

Comment: I do say wtf when I see this, but even read the thing I still don't know your intention

Comment: @Ooker Lorem ipsum is often used as placeholder text in software.

Comment: @fi12 i know that. I just don't know how the placeholder text is related to learning language.

Comment: It's in Latin, so not just placeholder, so it may motivate people to learn the language and understand what does it mean.

Comment: There is nothing to understand because Lorem Ipsum is NOT Latin.It is constructed from Latin but is non-sensical.

Answer (score 3):

## Say What?

"I have no idea. It's all Greek to me."

Answer (score 3):

## **The Polyglots' Hub**

This is just a forked version of Quill's proposal. I think the word `Polyglot` goes well with the language learners.

Answer (score 0):

## [Babel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylon#Name)

to make clear that here many languages are practiced, of course the link to [babelfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_races_and_species_in_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Babel_fish) could be a bit negative, as this would put a stronger emphasize on translation rather than learning a language.

Answer (score -1):

## The Language Factory

It gives the sense that we are building our language skills, which is what language learning is all about.

Comment: To me, it imparts more of a "we're talking about conlangs here" type deal...

Answer (score -3):

If it's obvious that it's the chat room, then I would petition for it to have the name "Language Learning" or something of that sort but display in a different language each time it is seen ("Aprendizaje de Idiomas", "Sprachen Lernen", "изучение языка", etc.).  The English default can be used in places where it's not obvious that the chat room is what's being referred to.

Comment: This would be something managed by Stack Exchange chat, so we can't really change how it's displayed. Also your answer is very close to my (heavily downvoted) answer ;)

Comment: @Quill Well they wanted creativity so I'm thinking out of the box.  If demand is high enough Stack Exchange could totally implement something like this too.

Comment: If this could work, this is a great idea. +1

Answer (score -4):

## Language Learning

We use the default name for the chat room, as it may be confusing what the room's purpose is for.

Comment: Creative names please!

Comment: It's not about _Creative names_ @PythonMaster, it's about names. Don't rush to name your chatroom. Worldbuilding still has their chatroom named Worldbuilders General Chat

Answer (score -5):

## I don't speak English

It is a common answer (can be a pun, can be a real answer) when someone asking "Can you speak English?" to a native people in a non-English speaking country (not sure if it's only in my country). Given that the site is about language learning, yet the only "legal" language is English, I think this is a good name.

Other variations might be: I don't know English, I can't speak English.

Answer (score -6):

### *talkōną ‎

It's the Proto-Germanic word for "talk." I would have gone back farther, but it wasn't recognizable.

Answer (score -6):

**Repeat Please?**

Just because we language learners a lot of times probably won't get what was said on the first saying by someone who knows the language well.